# javascript mystery - how functions get access to outside variables

Tags: javascript

I am kind of new to javascript and trying to understand some non trivial - *at least so i hope :)* things.

my question is general, but i have a specific example which can help me ask my question and help you understand what i mean.

the example:

```
function updateBookmark(bookmark){
    var index = _.findIndex($scope.bookmarks, function(b){
        return b.id == bookmark.id;
    });
    return index;
}
```

obviously the findIndex function is **declared somewhere** (in our case - lodash.js) 
and it gets two parameters (at least two visible parameters: a data set, and a function)

## first question:

in this example, **what is b**? how does b gets its value? i understand b is each of the data set's objects, but i mean - **what is going behind the scenes here so b will be what it is?**?

## second question:

the author chose to pass an anonymous function which equals b.id with bookmark.id,

i understand that he can use bookmark.id where he is using it, but **how does findIndex has access to this bookmark?!**

this function as i concluded earlier is declared somewhere else, does it get all the variables in the scope some how?
**what is going on here?**

Thanks in advance to responders and sorry for the messy question...
Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite some things, it becomes easier to understand.

Starting with the last portion:

```
// Q: "How does `findIndex`have access to `bookmark`"
_.findIndex(bookmarks, function (b) { });
// A: "It doesn't."
var bookmark = { id: 1 };
var bookmarks = [ /* ... */ ];
function compareWithBookmark( test ) {
  return test.id === bookmark.id;
}
_.findIndex(bookmarks, compareWithBookmark);
```

As you can see, findIndex doesn't actually have any access to bookmark.
Rather, it has access to a function which it can pass a value to test, and that function will return whether that test passed or failed.

Under the covers of `.findIndex` or `[].map` or `[].filter`, they're all just taking a function, making a loop, passing each element into the function one at a time, and doing something with the return value.

```
function findIndex (array, test) {
  var index = -1;
  var i = 0;
  var l = array.length;
  var el;
  var result;

  for (; i < l; i += 1) {
    el = array[i];       // <-- how `b` got its value
    result = test(el, i, array); // <-- test(b)
    if (!!result) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return index;
}
```

The different functions would do different things with the results (`map` returns a new array which contains each `result`, `filter` returns an array where only `!!result` tests passed, et cetera), but all of them do this inner-looping.

This is also a pretty gross simplification of the looping structure and considerations, but it's exactly what's driving your expected behaviour.

## Edit

Here is a full usage of the function I just defined, plus the array, plus the object I'm checking.

```
var bookmarks = [
  { id:  2 },
  { id:  3 },
  { id:  6 },
  { id: 14 }
];

var bookmark = { id: 3 };
function compareBookmarkIdTest (el) {
  return el.id === bookmark.id;
}

var index = findIndex(bookmarks, compareBookmarkIdTest);
index; // 1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helps much more than voting my question down and leaving :)

the function in my example does: return b.id == bookmark.id; so when findIndex uses it - it equals b.id with the number evaluated from bookmark.id? for example, it replaces the bookmark.id to 5?

are the two exclamation marks (!!) on purpose? if so - what do they mean?
can you also explain how the b argument got its value?
sorry for harassing you :-/

Comment: Have a look at my edits. I've written not only a version of findIndex, but also written how it would be used in a very simple example.  Track through the flow of that little program. You'll see exactly where the value of `b` comes from. `!result` is "not `result`" `!!result` is "not not result". The difference is that `!result` is always Boolean, `result` could be anything... ...so `!!result` is guaranteed to be Boolean, too. Don't worry about it, in 95% of the cases that matter `if (result)` and `if (!!result)` do the same thing.